# image position was wrong in block using CGContextDrawImage

Tags: ios, core-text, cgcontextdrawimage

**I was followed by [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app) to draw text using Core Text, and I want to add web image to the view.
when I used the code below, everything works fine except waiting the downloading time.**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFrameDraw((CTFrameRef)self.coreTextFrame, context);

    for (NSArray *imageData in self.images) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageData objectAtIndex:0]]]];
        CGRect imageBounds = CGRectFromString([imageData objectAtIndex:1]);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, imageBounds, image.CGImage);
    }
}
```

[image: the correct effect]

**but this code blocked the main thread, and when I replace the code like this:**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFrameDraw((CTFrameRef)self.coreTextFrame, context);

    for (NSArray *imageData in self.images) {

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  [imageData objectAtIndex:0]]];
        __block UIImage *image = nil;
        CGRect imageBounds = CGRectFromString([imageData objectAtIndex:1]);

        AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(UIImage *downloadImage){
            image = downloadImage;
            CGContextDrawImage(context, imageBounds, image.CGImage);
        }];

        [operation start];

    }
}
```

**it becomes wired, the position of image is wrong.**
[image: the wrong effect]